# Setting SameSite cookie attributes in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, dom, cookies, nuxt.js

I'm learning Nuxt.js and I assigned some data to `localStorage` (using `localStorage.getItem()` and `localStorage.setItem()`) which worked great, but I'm getting a warning: `Cookie “myCookieName” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute.`

After reading about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite), I think I would like to set it to `strict`, but I have no idea where to actually set it.

Any tips would be highly appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [cookie-universal-nuxt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-universal-nuxt) package for playing with cookies (there are many others but this is perfect for SSR).

Then after you can set cookie attributes via this module options in `nuxt.config.js`

```
{
  modules: [
    ['cookie-universal-nuxt', { SameSite: 'Strict' }],
 ]
}
```